# How to define instance method in ruby dynamically?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to dynamically create instance method of child class through class method of parent class.

```
class Foo
  def self.add_fizz_method &body
    # ??? (This is line 3)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end
Bar.new.fizz #=> nil

class Bar
  add_fizz_method do
    p "i like turtles"
  end
end
Bar.new.fizz #=> "i like turtles"
```

What to write on line #3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use `define_method` like this:

```
class Foo
  def self.add_fizz_method &block
    define_method 'fizz', &block
  end
end

class Bar < Foo; end

begin
  Bar.new.fizz 
rescue NoMethodError
  puts 'method undefined'
end

Bar.add_fizz_method do
  p 'i like turtles'
end
Bar.new.fizz
```

output:

```
method undefined
"i like turtles"
```

Comment: almost what I need. problem is - &block`s self should be instance of Bar. so it would be possible to write something like this: class Bar ; add_fizz_method do ; p self.bar_name ; end ; end

Comment: try `p self.class` below `p 'i like turtles'`. `self` already is an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: Btw: if you want to return `nil` instead of throwing a `NoMethodError` before having called `add_fizz_method`, you can declare an empty `fizz` method in the `Foo` class.

Comment: heh... I wrote `define_method 'fizz', do &block.call end` previously. tyvm. got what I needed and learned a thing.

Answer (score 11):

```
define_method 'fizz' do
  puts 'fizz'
end
```

...or accepting a block

```
define_method 'fizz', &block
```